# Rails 4 use params from controller in a callback (model) function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

Rails 4, Ruby 2.3.1 (noob alert)

I have a restaurant reservation app.  before a reservation is saved I need to check the db to ensure there is a table available. To do this I check the date and time selected in the form with a count:

```
Reservation.where(r_date:params[:r_date],r_time:params[:r_time]).count < 3
```

assuming the restaurant has 3 tables.  If the count is more than 3 then there is not a table available.

How do I get the params from @reservation in the controller to the callback function in the model?

Comment: Where is `@reservation` var in your controller and what is "callback function in the model"? It is not quite clear what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `before_save` method to check availability, and invalidate the model, canceling the save, if there are no tables available.

In your controller:

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)
    if @reservation.save
      redirect_to reservation_path(@reservation)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def reservation_params
    params[:reservation].permit(:r_date, :r_time)
  end
end
```

Then, in your model:

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Model
  before_save :check_availability

  private

  def check_availability
    reservation_count = Reservation.where(r_date: self.r_date, r_time: self.r_time).count
    if reservation_count > 3
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

I haven't had a chance to test this code, so please let me know if you have any problems.

Edit: explanation

Comment: thank you ajpocus!  How do I add a flash or error to this callback?

Comment: No problem @phillipjones1! You should be able to set `flash[:notice] = "your message here"` before the `render 'new'` call.